# Online factorial program in nodejs

Tags: ajax, node.js, socket.io

I want to write a nodejs program that computes factorial of all numbers less than 30 which is very popular among new programmers.

```
fact(0) = 1
fact(i) = i*fact(i-1)
```

But this time I want the nodejs to print the output online on the web browser of the client.

I know how to write the code for factorial, but I don't know how to update the clients view whenever a new factorial number is computed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all processor intensive tasks should be done on other processes. That's because doing so in your node HTTP server will block the main event loop!

You can do the calculation on other process(es) and transfer the results to your **node.js** server process via standard streams, sockets, a database, etc.

My personal opinion is, **node.js** is not the right tool for doing such calculation (I'm being convinced that it might work for small numbers)

This article on [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com) walks you through [Building a Real-time, Polyglot Application with Node.js, Ruby, MongoDB and Socket.IO](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/realtime-polyglot-app-node-ruby-mongodb-socketio).

---

`> I just want to know how to show my output to the client whenever something happens`:

In order to do this with **socket.io**, you need to install it first:

```
npm install socket.io
```

Then in your node application:

*Note that in this example, I'm pushing a message to clients on an interval.*

```
var http = require('http'),
    io;

var html = "<!doctype html>" +
    "<title>Socket.IO Example</title>" +
    "<div id=\"number\"></div>" +
    "<script src=\"/socket.io/socket.io.js\"></script>" +
    "<script>" +
    "var socket = io.connect()," +
    "numberElement = document.getElementById('number');" +
    "socket.on('message', function (data) {" +
    //"numberElement.innerText = data;" +
    "numberElement.innerHTML = data;" +
    "});" +
    "</script>";

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.statusCode = 200;
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    response.end(html);
});

server.listen(8080);

io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

function push(socket) {
    var i = 0;
    return function () {
        socket.send(String(i++ % 3600));
    };
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var interval = setInterval(push(socket), 1000);
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        clearInterval(interval);
    });
});
```

[Here](https://c9.io/fardjad/socket_io_demo) is the full project on [c9.io](http://c9.io).

Comment: *"of all numbers less than 30"*, that won't put Node in much of a sweat at all. The question is more related to getting the results back to the user, not how to build CPU-intensive Node applications.

Comment: @robertklep `> Update the clients view whenever a new factorial number is computed` looks like the OP is trying to do a CPU intensive task on the **node.js** server which is totally a bad practice. No matter how small is the number, it WILL block the main event loop while it's calculating the factorial. Unless he/she wants to do the calculation on another **node.js** process. While it's possible, I think this can be done faster and more efficiently on other languages/interpreters.

Comment: @fardjad the main application is not the factorial. I just want to know how to show my output to the client whenever something happens

Comment: @fardjad for funsies, time how long it takes to just call `child_process.exec()`, and compare that to how long it takes to calculate the factorial of 150. Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/5488842).

Comment: haha @robertklep I will definitely look at that gist! Thanks : )

Comment: @fardjad you're focussing on an issue which isn't at all an issue here. Yes, processor-intensive tasks block the main loop, but like I said, Node is a quick calculator and your suggestions **for this case** are overkill. My laptop reaches 2500 requests *per second* with 1000 connections calculating `150!` for each connection...

Comment: @robertklep OK, I'm convinced :)

Comment: Thank you for the code, right now I have problem installing socket.io and as soon as I solve that, I will test this code ;)

Comment: I ran your code but I'm not getting any data on the page! I ran it and it only shows the numbers in terminal!!!!

Comment: @robertklep did you check it in firefox?

Comment: @emab replace `numberElement.innerText` (in the `html` variable) by `numberElement.innerHTML` to make it work in FF.

Comment: @robertklep what if I wanted to have a stop bottom on the client page?!

Comment: @emab try posting that as a new question, it goes beyond the scope of this question really